# Gostaria de separa uma string em PHP e pegar dado especifico

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma view pegando dados de um arquivo txt mas a função está retornando a linha inteira e eu quero somente a coluna. Teria uma forma de trazer somente a coluna especifica.

```
public function carregarPA($arq,$linha){
    $arquivo = file($arq);
    $y = $linha - 1;
    return $arquivo[$y];
}
```

No monete o retorno é o seguinte:

67  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   82  0   68  12  0   0   2   .00

Eu quero somente o numero "82". Já tentei com o explode() mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

Exemplo

```
substr($arquivo[$y],17,2)
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.